# AWS ELB ssl with multiple domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon ELB and have https setup with a certificate, however I need to support many domains (several thousand).  Is there a way to have an ELB forward port 443 to the resolving EC2 instance(s) and let them handle https? or would there be an alternative way to support this? From what I've seen it looks like you can only one listener to 443 with a single certificate associated.

Comment: You can now have multiple domains, simply use Amazon ACM  (AWS Certificate Manager) to create a certificate with multiple domains, then use that in your ELB. https://console.aws.amazon.com/acm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, an ELB can only have 1 associated certificate.  Assuming you aren't in a situation where a wildcard cert would work (e.g. *.example.com) you won't be able to use ELB the way that the GUI makes it seem like it should work.  This is because ELB does not support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) which is what makes something like apache able to bind multiple SSL domains to a single host.

That said, there is a workaround.  You can forward 443 through your ELB directly to the assigned server. This is done by setting up port 443 in TCP pass-through mode rather than in HTTPS mode. To do that:

1. Go to the AWS console and select the ELB you want to edit.
2. Choose "Listeners" tab.
3. Select "Edit"
4. Change the "Load Balancer and Instance Protocols to "TCP" (see screenshot)
5. Set the Load Balancer and Instance Ports to 443

Alternatively, if you don't yet have an HTTPS listener, choose "Add" in step 3.

[image: AWS ELB Listener Dialog]

Note, setting it up this way will force your EC2 Instances to encrypt/decrypt traffic which will be an additional load on your EC2 CPU.

Comment: Thank you, although the only options I have are HTTPS and HTTP - no TCP

Comment: I added a screenshot from one of my ELBs. There should definitely be an option.

Comment: Thank you, just realized I had an application load balancer instead of classic, this seems to work perfect!

Comment: Now LB supports SNI - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do this now.

You need AWS ACM certificates. Assuming you already have one:
Select your load balancer and Under "Listeners", check the https listener and open the certificate selector on "View/edit certificates".

[image]

Then in the selection menu use the '+' or '-' buttons to add or remove ACM certificates from said balancer:

[image]